# Vue.js multiple check box

Tags: arrays, vue.js

I  have 3 check boxes . Want to get result like `{ceheckboxName1:value,ceheckboxName2:value,ceheckboxName3:value}`.You can see my code for better understand.

```
 <li>
    <input name="" type="checkbox" value="100" v-model="checkedNames"  id="incall">
    <label for="incall">Incall</label>
    <div class="pull-right price-now-right"><p>100</p></div>
</li>
<li>
    <input name="" type="checkbox"  value="200" v-model="checkedNames"   id="">
    <label for="lbl">view</label>
    <div class="pull-right price-now-right"><p>100</p></div>
</li>
<li>
    <input name="" type="checkbox" value="On Request" v-model="checkedNames"  id="overnight">
    <label for="ovr">lmm</label>
    <div class="pull-right price-now-right"><span>On request</span></div>
</li>
```

Comment: Where is your JS code?  And what isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

Give each checkbox a `:value="true"` (yes, the `:` is important) and `v-model="checkboxName1"` (2, 3, etc.). That will automatically set `this.checkboxName1` to `true` if checked.

Then, in your `data` function:

```
data() {
    return {
        checkboxName1: false,
        checkboxName2: false,
        checkboxName3: false,
    };
}
```

`this.$data` will contain your desired format.